# Two questions about distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

1. Is it correct to assume that:
   $$\int f(x)\,P.v.\left(\frac{1}{x-a}\right)\delta(x-a)\,dx\,=\,0$$ ?
   Where the delta function is taken as a measure and $f(x)$ is a test function (it might be good to know what conditions it has to satisfy), and P.v. denotes the principal value.
2. I know that squaring a delta function is undefined object. However, in what sense would it be possible to just say that the dagger operation (Hermitian conjugate) leaves this undefined object unaffected when it appears inside an integral (that contains compact support)?

Comment: There is no meaning to product of general distributions, so what us the meaning of principal value multiplied by a Dirac delta ?

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not an ideal situation.. Nevertheless, this situation appears in some fundamental problems of physics. Note that the principal value is identically 0 at the point that the delta function is effective.

Comment: The Dirac or the principal value in physics usually come from approximation arguments, so if this kind of integral appears it usually means that a forbidden limit was taken.

Comment: Yes, taking limits in QFT is sometime is a real mess..

Answer (score 1):

The value of that expression isn't well-defined.

Taking $f(x)=x$ we have on one hand,
$$
\int f(x) \, \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, \delta(x) \, dx
= \int x \, \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, \delta(x) \, dx
= \int 1 \, \delta(x) \, dx
= 1
$$
since $x \, \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} = 1$ (constant),
and on the other hand,
$$
\int f(x) \, \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, \delta(x) \, dx
= \int \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, x\, \delta(x) \, dx
= \int \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, 0 \, dx
= 0
$$
since $x \, \delta(x) = 0.$

Contradiction!

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know that the product of x and p.v. is a constant?

Comment: @Yair. By definitions,
$$
\int x \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} x \frac{1}{x} \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} 1 \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int 1 \, \varphi(x) \, dx
$$
for every test function $\varphi$ and so $x \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} = 1.$

Comment: Thanks. Just one last little thing, is it consistent to say that the principal value can also be defined as a measure: $$P.v.\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\frac{1}{x}
\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}
x=0\\
x\neq0
\end{array}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Yair. A measure is a function that takes a set and assigns a value.

Comment: Isn't this in line with what I wrote? I mean, I defined p.v. as a mapping that assign a value for every number of the domain (the set R).

Comment: @Yair. You give a mapping that takes a *point* in $\mathbb R$ but a measure on $\mathbb R$ is a mapping that takes a *subset* of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Well.. isn't a point in R considered a subset of R? The Dirac delta function (as a measure) is defined by using the same construction, and just the codomain differs.

Comment: @Yair. A point $x \in \mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R.$ The singleton set $\{x\}$ is however a subset of $\mathbb R.$ As a measure, $\delta$ is defined by $\delta(A)=1$ if $0\in A$, $=0$ if $0\not\in A.$ As a distribution, $\delta$ is defined by $\langle\delta, f\rangle=f(0)$ for every test function $f.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: By the way, if there is any chance that you'll be able to take a look once a paper that I'm currently writing will become ready that will be highly appreciated. Let me know if that might be possible for you.

Comment: @Yair. What is the paper about?

Comment: Fractalic dynamics in quantum mechanics. I wrote it from the perspective of a physicist, but clearly it will be good to have a mathematician to look at it before sending it to publication.

Comment: @Yair. I have not only studied mathematics but also physics, but I'm working as a programmer.

Comment: So.. it will be my pleasure to have your opinion once it will become ready. Even undergraduate knowledge is enough to understand everything. How would it be possible to sent it to you?

Comment: @Yair. You can reach me on Facebook (https://fb.com/md2perpe), on Twitter (https://twitter.com/md2perpe) or email (md2perpe@gmail.com).

Comment: Thank you so much! note that it will probably take me at least a month to get back to you as this is still currently in preparation.